# Using Parse Framework with Xcode 6.2 - ie. 64 bit

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I added the latest framework 1.64 to my project and now it won't build with the following errors:-

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke214 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke311 in Parse(PFObject.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(Parse.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFConfig.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFQuery.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(Parse.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFConfig.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyPin.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFInstallation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
```

Seems to suggest that the Parse framework isn't 64bit. Any ideas how to fix, as all apps submitted to the App Store have to be 64bit.

Comment: It looks like you did not add the Bolts.framework to your project. It should be included with the SDK download.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and first off you may try to overcome that by upgrading [Parse.framework](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads) since it already supported 64-bit. Also make sure you setup architectures correctly for that. You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509641/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-architectures-to-support-64-bit-added) out for more details. Also install new [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios). In my case once I've done the above, my errors are gone. Hope this helps.