# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when Architectures to support 64-bit added

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, xcode6, 32bit-64bit

I've been trying to enable 64-bit in my project as this is now a requirement for submitting app to the App Store. What I've done so far to convert my app to support 64-bit is actually following others' questions/answers I've searched on StackOverflow and what I've found came down to

- Set **Architectures** to **"Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)"**
- Set **Valid Architectures** to **"arm64 armv7 armv7s"**
- Set **Build Active Architectures Only** to **"No"** (some mentioned this, so I just tried it out)

Those above create errors of **Apple Mach-O Linker Error**. I totally got 13 errors of them. They're shown in details as pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It looks to me like a Parse framework issue but I'm too new to know that for sure. Even so, I've tried to to replace my current Parse.framework with a new one I downloaded from its website. It created even more issues that might be caused by my bad on how I replaced that new framework. I've searched on Parse website what the best way to update framework but answers I found seem there's no certain way to do it. Anyway I followed this https://parse.com/questions/what-is-the-best-way-to-rollout-new-parse-changes but it's not working.

So I decided to drop my question here hoping someone tapping in to guide me the right path to go before I fall into the long wrong one. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: first thing first: clean & rebuild the project

Comment: Thanks I did that already but no help

Comment: Since Parse framework [already supported 64-bit](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-compile-the-ios-sdk-for-64-bit), the best bet would be [upgrading the framework](https://parse.com/questions/sdk-upgrade-on-ios).

Comment: Right as I mentioned towards the end of my question that I've been trying to upgrade  the framework but it created some mess at the moment. Perhaps I should figure this out first. Your second link is useful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by successfully upgrading Parse.framework (also thanks to @Raptor) to the latest downloaded from [Parse website](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads).